# Function whose graph is a cone

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I hope your day is going well.

Let $u : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function on a open convex bounded set.

I read "Let $v$ be the convex function whose graph is the cone with
vertex $(x_{0},u(x_{0}))$ and the base $\Omega$ with $v =0$ on $\partial{\Omega}$. We have $v \in \mathcal{C}^{0}(\text{adh}(\Omega),\mathbb{R})$".

I'm sorry but this function exists ? And how does he know that it is continuous. I don't say it don't exist, of course. I trust the author but may anyone give me a expression of that function ? Because it is not quite obious for me.
Maybe we can use convex conjuguate I don't know.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

An explicit expression for the function may be impossible to write down without describing the set $\Omega$ in more detail, which is why the definition of the function is given as it is.  What you know about $v$ is:

1. $v$ is a convex function, so given $x,y\in {\cal C}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have $v(\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y) \leq \lambda v(x) + (1-\lambda)v(y)$.
2. $v=0$ on $\partial \Omega$
3. $v\in C^0(\mathrm{adh}(\Omega), {\mathbb R})$

and what you know about the cone ${\cal C}$ is that it has a vertex at $(x_0, u(x_0))$ and base $\Omega$.  So, if you take any point on $\Omega$ and connect it with a straight line to the vertex $x_0, u(x_0))$ then than line is part of the cone ${\cal C}$.  A straight line can be mapped to an interval (say $[0,1]$ for the sake of argument) and intervals are convex, so you know that $v$ exists at every point of the domain ${\cal C}$.

So you have enough information to know that such a function $v$ exists, and if you need to calculate explicit values you'll need to define $\Omega$ explicitly first.  If you do, then the convexity of $v$ and the boundary conditions will constrain what expression $v$ can have, but you may still need to make some choices (of constants or additional constraints) to find a single $v$.

You haven't provided any reference to where this comes from, but this way of starting things is common when the aim of the analysis is to understand what *classes* of functions $v$ are admissible for a given domain.  As you continue reading you may find that the author narrows down the type of function $v$ can be further.

Lastly: for this kind of thing, try sketching the domain for simple (and complicated) $\Omega$ to help build intuition.  If you let $\Omega$ be the boundary of the unit ball in ${\mathbb R}^2$ first and draw ${\cal C}$ it should be much easier to see how such a convex $v$ could be found.